# Как передать объект в метод класса? Python

Tags: python, классы, объекты

Подскажите пожалуйста как передать объект(r1) в метод класса(add_record)?
У меня ошибка :(

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        self.records = []

    def add_record(self, some_record):
        self.records.append(some_record)

class Record:
    def __init__(self, amount, comment):
        self.amount = amount
        self.comment = comment

r1 = Record(120, 'Пирожок')

Calculator.add_record(r1)

File "c:/Dev/hw_python_oop/homework.py", line 22, in <module>
    Calculator.add_record(r1)
TypeError: add_record() missing 1 required positional argument: 'some_record'
```

Comment: Calculator().add_record(r1). Мне сейчас неудобно разжевывать это.

Comment: Вы не создали экземпляр класса `Calculator`.

Answer (score 7):

как написали в комментарии, вы не создали экземпляр класса `Calculator`, после создания экземпляра класса вы можете обращаться к его методам.

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        self.records = []

    def add_record(self, some_record):
        self.records.append(some_record)

class Record:
    def __init__(self, amount, comment):
        self.amount = amount
        self.comment = comment


r1 = Record(120, 'Пирожок')
с1 = Calculator(10)
с1.add_record(r1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял)